# Python - cannot import name

Tags: python

I think just the code will be enough for you to understand everything

exampleforstack.py

```
from psgss import login,password 

print(login,password)
```

psgss.py

```
login = "login"
password = 33
```

and here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b:\vse parsers\exampleforstack.py", line 4, in <module>
    from psgss import login,password
ImportError: cannot import name 'login' from 'psgss' (b:\vse parsers\psgss.py)
```

idk what to do, this error appears every time i try to import any files.
Modules are imported without errors, problems appear only with files,
thanks in advance

Comment: "this error appears every time i try to import any files modules are imported without errors, problems appear only with files" I don't understand the distinction you are trying to draw here. Your `psgss.py` file *defines* the `psgss` *module*. I also can't reproduce the error your describe. What happens when you try `import psgss`? If that works, what does `vars(psgss)` tell you?

Comment: Do you have a stale `psgss.pyc` file lying around that might have been created from an older version of `psgss.py` that *didn't* define `login`?

Comment: some people have an error with which they can't import modules(kinda selenium or something) and files, but I can't import only files, it was just a clarification

Comment: first you could check if you really have `login` in this file - and it has to be global variable, not local variable inside function. You could use `import psgss` and `print( psgss.__file__ )` to check path of imported module - maybe it loads from different file.  And then you could check what is in file - `print( open(psgss.__file__).read() )`

Comment: I burned out and decided to just reinstall python and vs studio , now everything works, I have no idea what the problem was, but thank you all for your help

Answer (score -1):

I see a couple potential problems, depending on your setting of PYTHONPATH, what other files are present, and details of your invocation:

Imports should ideally either be in a directory listed on PYTHONPATH, if they're outside the current package. This probably isn't directly relevant to you though, since you're likely thinking of `psgss.py` and `exampleforstack.py` as parts of the same package.

If you're not importing from something outside the current package, i.e. something on the PYTHONPATH, it should be in a directory with an `__init__.py`. (IIRC, `__init__.py` is no longer strictly required, but you still see it a lot, so try adding it if you don't have it.)  Adding `__init__.py` is unlikely to be enough by itself, though. It effectively says `psgss.py` and `exampleforstack.py` are part of the same package, but that's *not* what you're conveying in your imports as written.

Try changing the import line to `from .psgss import login, password`. The period before "psgss" is critical, since it tells Python to look for the file / module in the *same* directory as the invoking code. (This is a difference in "relative imports" versus "absolute imports", and changed in Python 2 -> Python 3.  Python 2 tried to be much more forgiving of such omissions, but would occasionally import from the PYTHONPATH when an import from the local directory was intended. Python 3 is more strict, to avoid importing global packages when local ones are intended - or vice versa.)

However, you're likely still not done, depending on where you are on the command-line when doing the import. Python expects you to be outside that "local package" at invocation, so the expected file structure is something like this:

```
package_support/
   +------entrypoint.py
   +------package/
             +-------__init__.py
             +-------exampleforstack.py
             +-------psgss.py
```

In `exampleforstack.py` you would have `from .psgss import login, password`, but you would run the code from the `package_support/` directory, and `entrypoint.py` would have a line like `import package.exampleforstack` which would load `exampleforstack.py`, which would load `psgss.py`.  Other things that go in `package_support/` would be a README, non-Python scripts, and possibly code / directories specifically for packaging & deploying the `package/` contents.

Comment: The error message already suggests that the correct file is used. It reports the path ``b:\vse parsers\psgss.py`` imported by ``b:\vse parsers\exampleforstack.py``.